# install mac osx el capitan in vmware with .dmg suffix file

Tags: vmware, osx-elcapitan

I 've installed unlocker but I want to install mac el capitan in vmware ..el capitan I .dmg installer file extension is not .vmx and when I run vmware error

1.sata harddrive unsuccessful virtual 2.sata CDROM Drive unsuccessful

I have

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to install a Mac OSX on a ESXi host you will need to patch this with an ESXi Unlocker. Also to install MAC OSx you need to log into your ESXi Server within C# Client trying to install it from vCenter will give issues.

I would Recommend sticking with OSX - Mavericks for this as i have notice issues with El Capitan and Yosemite. while running on my ESXi Host Server.

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/files/file/339-unlocker/